# VSCode: configure the built-in code formatter (js-beautify)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual-Studio-Code has the ability to beautify html/js code. I read that it is based on js-beautify. Can I add certain parameters to my settings.json to configure the beautifier? I.e. I would like to change the --wrap-line-length parameter of js-beautify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vMarch

I had to add this line to settings.json in VScode to switch of beautifier's line wrap:

```
"html.format.wrapLineLength":-1
```